# How can I store items in localstorage before running a test with Laravel Dusk?

Tags: laravel, local-storage, laravel-dusk

I'm using **Laravel 5.4** and I wonder if it is possible to save items in the *localStorage* before running a test in **Laravel Dusk**.   For example, imagine that you want to test some behaviours that should happen after completing a long list of things that are stored in the browser's *localStorage*.

Is it possible to have them in the *localStorage* before running the test that requires them? If so, how would you do it before a test?

Of course I could write a script that goes through the long process of filling the *localStorage* manually, as a regular user would do it.  But running the same long lasting method over and over just to test bits of functionality doesn't feel quite right.

Thanks for your help, beforehand.

Comment: Yes you can store in browser local storage but if you want to store sensitive data then the session is the best option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gurpal,  I need some information stored in the localStorage as an initial environment setup for three or four tests in Laravel Dusk. So I believe there must be a way to set those initial parameters before using the $browser assertions.

Comment: You can initialize the `localStorage` with `$browser->script()`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: you are welcome @Tedeo Rod. go to this link for more information
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/saving-raw-data-into-local-storage-in-laravel-51

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir, that's exactly what I want...  I'm trying this but I'm getting errors:              

$browser->script("window.localStorage.setItem('picture-dictionary', 'bar' ); ")
                ->visit("/demo")
                ->pause(2000)
                ->assertSee("TRY IT");

Comment: You can't chain after `script()`: `$browser->script("window.localStorage.setItem('picture-dictionary', 'bar' ); "); $browser->visit("/demo")->pause(2000)->assertSee("TRY IT");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. This is how I did it, thanks to @JonasStaudenmeir comments I managed to do it somehow, so all the credit goes to Jonas!!

So, for the other troubled souls that can find this useful... In my case I needed the localStorage to have some initial data. But as mentioned, I was getting errors, either chaining ->script() or not. So basically I had to visit the page twice, to prevent the errors from showing and to reflect the stored data.

```
    $browser->visit("/demo")
        ->script("window.localStorage.setItem('picture-dictionary', 'bar')");

    $browser->visit("/demo")
        ->assertSee("TRY IT");
```